# Font-scaling using vw is correct on mobile but too large on desktop?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

Using a basic structure like:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h1>Some Text</h1>
</div>
```

With bootstrap as the default css and added css:

```
h1 { 5vw; }
```

Now on mobile this is a perfect size, on desktop it is way too big. Changing it to 1.5vw is perfect for desktop, but way too small on mobile. What's the trick here to get this sized like I see in examples for this?

Note, the styles for the parent is default 50% on col-md-6 in bootstrap.

Comment: Media queries...you already have them into Bootstrap..use them. ;)

Comment: Why would I want to use media queries when this is supposed to help avoid using media queries for every single element out there? The point of vw is to allow a smooth transition no matter the size of the viewport. a la https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 vw unit is equal to 1% of the viewport width, so if you've got it set to 5vw, you're essentially setting it to 5% of the overall width of your viewport, so 5% of your desktop width is going to be larger than 5% of your mobile width.

You'll need to use media queries to target your specific break points and adjust your vw units accordingly.

CSS Tricks has a great resource for frequently used media queries here: [Media Queries for Standard Devices](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: Well according to CSS Tricks (as you mentioned) this is supposed to be a way to avoid media queries for this kind of thing. It defeats the purpose of flowable font-size if you're setting font-size depending on breakpoints. As you can see in their article here: https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Comment: There's a gif further down in that article that demonstrates the way that the font-size changes, by increasing as the viewport increases. So yes, you don't need media queries if you want your font-size to increase with the size of the viewport, but my understanding was that you wanted a smaller font-size on a larger viewport? In which case, as far as I can tell, you'll need media queries.

Comment: Ok. I guess I was interpreting something else from that article. I think the example is in smaller viewport so it makes it seem like that. His saying this gets rid of media queries in that regard is a little off then I think. Basically this solution works well for mobile devices but for standard desktop sizes that doesn't work at all.

Comment: @o_O I don't know if you're also using vh units anywhere else in your code for layout purposes, but I found out yesterday that there's a bug on iOS 6-7 where it doesn't render vh units correctly - just thought I'd give you the heads up, it's something to bear in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page and look at the responsive utility classes.  I believe you can make two headers and have one hidden and one being shown depending on the device size.

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive